# Does SGI STL default allocator has memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

Two static members of __default_alloc_template have been taken for managing it's memory pool:

```
static char* _S_start_free;
static _Obj* __STL_VOLATILE _S_free_list[_NFREELISTS];
```

The allocator query heap space from operate system like follows:

```
_S_start_free = (char*)malloc(__n);
```

Then it use a part of this heap building a free memory list named _S_free_list.

But I can't find any code resbonsible for giving the memory back to operate system like:

```
free(_S_start_free);
```

I am confused.

- It depend on system's cleaning?
- Or Somewhere else has code for cleaning?

Help me.

Comment: it may not need to clean itself up if its going to live for the life of the program

Comment: On modern operating systems the programs run in virtual memory. When the program ends, the memory mapping just goes away.

Answer (score 0):

the answer for the first question is NO!
The default allocator *__default_alloc_template* of SGI STL frees its memory in it's *deallocate* function bellow:

```
 /* __p may not be 0 */
static void deallocate(void* __p, size_t __n) {
    if (__n > (size_t) _MAX_BYTES)
        malloc_alloc::deallocate(__p, __n);
    else {
        _Obj* __STL_VOLATILE*  __my_free_list
            = _S_free_list + _S_freelist_index(__n);
        _Obj* __q = (_Obj*)__p;

        // acquire lock
#       ifndef _NOTHREADS
        /*REFERENCED*/
        _Lock __lock_instance;
#       endif /* _NOTHREADS */
        __q -> _M_free_list_link = *__my_free_list;
        *__my_free_list = __q;
        // lock is released here
    }
}
```

When memory blocks needed to be released is lager then _MAX_BYTES(128 bytes, "the big block"), the function will call  *malloc_alloc::deallocate(__p, __n)* which simply calls the c malloc function to free the target blocks, giving them back to OS. Otherwise, instead of giving the memory back, for those small blocks, the function will put them back to the memory pool.

The philosophy behind this is reducing memory fragments as much as possible, since requesting and freeing space frequently will cause lots of memory fragments.

Comment: could you elaborate? this looks like its for deallocating objects allocated with it, not for cleaning up its internal structure.

Comment: Container like Vector is ,and did, responsible for releasing memory linked by _S_free_list. As for the memory pool, it will be take back when program exits. Usually, in an environment of single-threaded processes the memory pool is limited in a small space. That's the meaning of memory pool,  be the last man standing.

Comment: Thank for your answer.Sorry for my ambiguous description above.But what I concerned is,where is the end of the memory pool.

Comment: When the program ends. Sorry for the fault at the beginning of my answer, I was supposed to mean the answer of Does SGI STL default allocator has memory leak? is no.